# Countability: set of all real numbers containing only 4's

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is the set of all real numbers containing only 4's and possibly a decimal expansion countable? (Ex: the set contains 4, 44, 444, 4.44, 44.4, and so on).

I can't seem to find a bijection from N to this set so would intuitively not expect it to be countable, but at the same time I can't seem to apply Cantor's diagonalization argument here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of digits before the decimal point and a number after, that gives an easy bijection to $\mathbb N_0\times\mathbb N_0$ (you might have to exclude $(0,0)$), from which it should be simple to conclude what you want.

Comment: The number of digits after the decimal point can be infinite (for example, $\frac49$).

Comment: So that would mean that this is countable. And if we put the same question except that there can be 4's and 6's -- does this change anything?

Comment: If there can be 4s and 6s then everything changes.

Comment: Infinity is just one value, so that should be easy to handle.

Comment: Only using $4$ and $6$ for the fractional part is somewhat similar to building the cantor set starting with [0.4, 0.6], that might give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

There are finitely many $4$'s, and finitely many (possibly zero) digits before the decimal point.  Hence you seek a bijection between $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.